# Switching from catalog to product category/subcategory

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Hello I'm new to wordpress and working on a site that was developed by a different developer some years back. The site is using catalogs but is now being switched over to product categories. I have added the product categories and sub categories and linked the existing products to theses product categories. I also deleted the catalogs but the products aren't showing up on the site and I get a 404 error. I'm thinking I need to modify my taxonomy-product_categories.php file so that when a user clicks on parent product category it will then show links to that parents subcategory and then in the subcategory if it doesn't have a child category it shows products associated to that category/subcategory. Any help would be greatly appreciated and here is the code in my taxonomy-product_categories.php file:

Comment: It looks like the php code isn't displaying correctly on my post :/

Comment: Edit your question. Highlight your code, and click {} (or press Ctrl-K).